# Нумерация Latex

Tags: latex

Как задать начальное значение нумерации в ***Latex***.

Хочу чтобы нумерация начиналась с **2.13.** (к примеру) а не с **1**

Comment: В документации написано.

Comment: О нумерации _чего именно_ идет речь? Читайте, например, у [Львовского](https://mccme.ru/free-books/llang/newllang.pdf) про установку  значений счетчиков (команда `\setcounter`) (часть VII.3) и про подчинёные счетчики (часть VII..3.2) для придания им вида **2.13** (т.е. запись через точку).